# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]' for MySQL Image

Tags: vb.net

Im sorry to ask again about this question..
I just simplify this question..
This is my problem:

The error point is

```
Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
```

The code is

```
 Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
  Dim command As New MySqlCommand("select Imageblob from employeedetail where EmployeeID = '" + TextBoxEmployeeID.Text + "'", cn)        
 Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
 stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBNull` is what your query will return if the field in the table is of null value. You cannot cast a DBNull object to another type. You could do the following to avoid the error

```
Dim image As Byte()
If Not ISDBNull(DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())) Then image = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
```

This simply checks if the type of a field is `DBNull` before assigning it to `image`

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me to solve this problem! :D Once again thanks a lot p3tch